# Does System Utilities Slow Down My Pc Rather than Speeding It Up?

Tags: windows-7, performance-tuning

Is it correct that PC System Utilities are fake; they just slow down your PC rather than speed it up?  Can I trust PC System Utilities like 
System Mechanic, WinOptimizer, Advanced SystemCare PRO, TuneUp Utilities......................[I am using windows 7 64 bit]

On the other hand, some sites are telling that "Just use the built-in software and CCleaner from Piriform.  It hardly slows down your PC."

I need a clear concept on this matter. Please Help me to Know about that.

Comment: in short system utilities which just perform inbuilt activities in end user friendly way,obviously it might take up your part of process in your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not necessarily "fake", but having a lot of near useless programs running in the background hogging resources will always slow a machine down. Many of them have active scanners that constantly monitor your system as well, further slowing it down. Using more than one of them is probably overkill as well. I've seen several machines that were brought to their knees and had nothing but "cleanup" utilities running.

They can also damage Windows installs by deleting things that they believe are unnecessary but in reality are actually necessary for normal operation of the system. They're unlikely to delete anything vital, but you might have a different idea of "vital" to the authors of those programs and small things mysteriously stopping working can quickly get infuriating.

If you absolutely must have all those cleaner programs then the general advice is to disable **all** of their "run at startup" components and run them manually when needed.

I would second using CCleaner, but limit it to cleaning out temporary files and cached history and similar. That part is not doing anything with any risk to your system and leaves Windows to do its thing.